# Why is custom component not displayed in checkout in Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I thought adding a simple text to the checkout is easy. I read the docs and this also seemed to be easy.
Now I'm stuck..
I want it to show after the shipping methods first. Now I would be happy if it at least shows up anywhere on checkout :)

I created a module with is registered correctly (it contains two plugins which are already working).

Now I added my `checkout_index_index.xml` in `app/code/Me/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout/` with the following content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="me-mymodule-notice" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Me_Mymodule/js/view/checkout/shipping/item-notice</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

For the component I created a JS File here: `app/code/Me/Mymodule/view/web/js/view/checkout/shipping/item-notice.js` using this code:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Shipping/js/model/config'
    'mage/translate'
], function (Component, config, $t) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Me_Mymodule/checkout/shipping/notice'
        },
        config: config()
    });
});
```

As of the template definition above, I created a template in: `app/code/Me/Mymodule/view/web/template/checkout/shipping/notice.html`:

```
<div class="me-shipping-notice">
    <span class="separate-shipping-notice">
        THIS IS A TEST
    </span>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command and clear cache?

Comment: I missed to mention that :) Thanks @Nikolas, yes I did that!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself.
I checked many other posts with the same issue. But most of them were caused by syntax or typing errors in the layout XML or other files.

As I checked my files three times I didn't think it is caused by a syntax.

But I found a **missing colon** in the js file at line 3. After fixing this nothing happend but after **a second clear cache and reload** the template displayed in the frontend.